# How to merge an arbitrary number of arrays of object without duplicates?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, merge, duplicates

I have searched for this already but the solution was expecting that you know how many arrays you want to merge without duplicates.

I have to loop an object that contains an arbitrary number of arrays.
The object in the arrays is of type `{sType: string, nLaId: number, sname: string}`
To decide whether an object is a duplicate, one has to check whether there is another object with the same `sType` AND `nLaId`.

```
for(let key in objectContainingArrays){ // objectContainingArrays[key] is an array with specific objects of type {sType: string, nLaId: number, sname: string}
  // how would I merge the arrays here in the fastest way without duplicates?
}
```

If the solution is obvious or the solution can be find in another question, then I am sorry and I would appreciate a link. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using any libraries like underscore.js. You can first concatenate the arrays and then filter out the duplicates -

```
var mergedArray = [].concat.apply([], arrList);

var uniqueArray = mergedArray.filter((currentValue, index, arr) => 
  arr.findIndex (
     arrItem => (
        arrItem.sType === currentValue.sType && arrItem.nLaId === currentValue.nLaId)
     ) === index
);
```

Below is a sample -

```js
var arr1 = [{
    sType: "S1",
    nLaId: 1,
    sname: "N1"
  },
  {
    sType: "S2",
    nLaId: 2,
    sname: "N2"
  },
  {
    sType: "S3",
    nLaId: 3,
    sname: "N3"
  }
];
var arr2 = [{
    sType: "S2",
    nLaId: 2,
    sname: "N4"
  },
  {
    sType: "S2",
    nLaId: 2,
    sname: "N5"
  },
  {
    sType: "S1",
    nLaId: 3,
    sname: "N6"
  },
  {
    sType: "S4",
    nLaId: 3,
    sname: "N7"
  }
];
var arr3 = [{
    sType: "S1",
    nLaId: 1,
    sname: "N8"
  },
  {
    sType: "S2",
    nLaId: 2,
    sname: "N9"
  }
];

var arrList = [arr1, arr2, arr3];
var mergedArray = [].concat.apply([], arrList);
var uniqueArray = mergedArray.filter((currentValue, index, arr) => 
arr.findIndex(arrItem => (arrItem.sType === currentValue.sType && arrItem.nLaId === currentValue.nLaId)) === index);

console.log(uniqueArray);
```

Comment: Hey, thank you it did work. I will look up the underscore library, thank you for the recommendation